# lxml install on Python 3.5.1 error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, lxml

I just installed Python 3.5.1 on my MAC (latest OSX version). I would like to install lxml but am experiencing an error. I already have lxml functioning within Python 2.7. I tried using the following command:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
```

Per directions I found at http://lxml.de/installation.html However, I received the following message upon install:

```
George-Mac-Pro:BioasysDB BioASys$ STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

It appears as though lxml wants to install in my preexisting Python 2.7 rather than the newly installed Python 3.5. I also tried typing:

```
--upgrade
```

at the terminal prompt but got the following error message:

```
George-Mac-Pro:BioasysDB BioASys$ --upgrade
-bash: --upgrade: command not found
```

If I try to import `lxml` from within Python 3.5 I get the standard `ImportError` message:

```
No module named lxml
```

Any help on how to install lxml within my newly installed Python 3.5.1 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install with `pip3`:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

`pip` uses Python 2 , while `pip3` uses Python 3.

You can check what `pip3` you are using:

```
which pip3
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. That was what I was looking for. Thank you very much. George

Comment: I tried this and got `Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: On Windows you can install a binary: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml